Anonymously select data from Xarray
In pandas I can do something like -
pd.read_csv(path).loc[lambda df: df.col > 10, cols]

And I'm wondering if there's an equivalent in Xarray? I've tried -
xr.open_dataset(path)["var"].sel(
  time=lambda da: ~((da.time.dt.month == 2) & (da.time.dt.day == 29))
)

and
xr.open_dataset(path)["var"].loc[
  lambda da: ~((da.time.dt.month == 2) & (da.time.dt.day == 29))
]

Neither work. Obviously I can achieve this in two lines but it's cleaner code to read when in one line given I have to open and process similarly multiple datasets.

One way is to work with the boolean time index:
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
x = xr.DataArray(range(365), dims='time', coords={'time': time})


x.sel(time=~((x.time.dt.month == 2) * (x.time.dt.day == 29)))

using the * operator on the boolean indices with month==2 and day==29 I can produce a new index where only the overlap is True, and then invert using the ~ operator.
No need for an anonymous function.

The problem is not that the indexing doesn't work, it's that I want to do it on the read object before I save it to a variable. The syntax I've provided works over two lines.

your question is not clear, I suggest you add some more comments for clarity and if possible some example data
